# 10 Reputation gone from my account

Tags: support, reputation

Yesterday I logout my account with 308 Reputation.

This morning I downvoted an answer from the below question [mysql combine columns of multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079904/mysql-combine-columns-of-multiple-tables). So I got -1 reputation for down vote(307). But Now I have only 298 reputation.

Note: The downvoted answer is deleted from that post.

I have searched for my reputation history -10 votes not mentioned.

Can I know what happened?

Comment: Have you checked the "show removed posts" option at the bottom of your /reputation tab?

Comment: Did you check the `show removed posts` box at the bottom of the page? Most likely a question was deleted and an answer with one upvote went with it.

Comment: Ya. It already checked. Down voted question deleted from that question.

Comment: It could also be someone gave you an upvote, then undid that upvote within the grace period. The rep counter at the top of the page doesn't update automatically on such events (only a page reload does). At that moment your rep counter still shows 308 instead of 298.

Comment: As a consolation prize, you got a 100 rep association bonus for coming here. So now you have **398** rep. Problem solved? :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters got 308 reputation yesterday itself.

Comment: @BoPersson I agree with you. :-)

Comment: I don't see anything abnormal in your history. The 1 rep for the down vote was refunded after the post was deleted, you gained the association bonus .. it adds up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SE does some automated detecting and clean-up for suspicious voting patterns, you may have been affected by such a clean-up.

[Vote Fraud and You](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/)

[More Voting Anomalies](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/)